Restrict a specific group to access a directory and drive
I have created a group "restricted" and added a user "user1" to this group , how can I restrict this group to access some specified directory and drive.

The same way as you would grant permissions, because on Linux they're exclusive rather than additive:

Either change the directory's group using chgrp and remove group read/execute permissions with chmod g-rwx,

Or add an ACL entry on the directory that grants no permissions to the group, using setfacl -m g:thegroup:-.

Or set an ACL entry for the user that has no permissions, i.e. u:thegroup:-.


